# Are the two families of Johnson invariants of the Torelli groups related beyond the first one?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, mapping-class-groups, formality

$\newcommand{\sp}{\operatorname{Sp}(H)}$
$\newcommand{\gr}{\operatorname{gr}}$
$\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}$
$\newcommand{\der}{\operatorname{Der}}$
Johnson has defined two families $\tau_k,\tau_k'$ of invariants of Torelli groups. There is an obvious relation between the target of those invariants, and for $k=1$ in both cases the source is the abelianization of the Torelli group. It turns out they do coincide in that case. As far as I can tell he doesn't raise the question of how those are related for $k>1$, nor does he gives a reason why they shouldn't. So my question is this:

**Is there some, at least conjectural, relation between the two ?**

A bit more background: let $S=S_{g,1}$ be a surface of genus $g\geq 2$ with one boundary component and a base point chosen on $\partial S$. The mapping class group of $S$ acts (faithfully) on $\pi=\pi_1(S)$, and this induces the natural action on $H=H_1(S)$. The image of the action on $H$ is the symplectic group $\sp$, and its kernel is called the Torelli group $T$ of $S$.

The first construction is basically by derivating the action of $T$ on $\pi$. It goes as follows (see [here](https://massuyea.perso.math.cnrs.fr/notes/formality.pdf) for a nice review). The associated graded $\gr \pi$ of $\pi$. w.r.t to its lower central series $\Gamma$ is well-known to be the free $\mathbb{Z}$-Lie algebra on $H$. Johnson introduces a so-called $N$-series on $T$ by setting
$$
J^m=\{ f \in T, f \equiv \id \mod \Gamma^{m+1}\}.
$$

He shows there is an $\sp$-equivariant injective map of graded Lie algebras
$$
\gr_J T \hookrightarrow \der^+(\gr \pi)
$$
where $\der^+$ means derivations of positive degree. Let $\tau_k$ be the $k$th graded component of this map. One can then precompose with the canonical map
$$
\gr T \rightarrow \gr_J T
$$
from the associated graded of $T$ w.r.t to the lower central series.  In particular the first graded piece of $\gr T$ is $H_1(T)$.

The second construction is more geometric, using some sort of family of Abel-Jacobi maps parametrized by the Torelli space (ie the space of complex structures on $S$ modulo the action of $T$) he gives an $\sp$-equivariant map
$$
\tau_k':H_k(T) \longrightarrow H_{k+2}(Jac(S))\cong \wedge^{k+2} H
$$
where $Jac$ is the Jacobian (see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1114)).

Using the symplectic form to identify $H\cong H^*$ there is an obvious map
$$
\wedge^{k+2} H \longrightarrow \der^k(\gr \pi)
$$
which is injective for $k=1$. Johnson shows that $\tau_1$ lands in this subspace and, after precomposing with the map from $H_1(T)$, that it actually coincides with $\tau_1'$. In fact those maps becomes isomorphisms over $\mathbb{Q}$ which was the main motivation to define all of this.

So the question is: what about higher values of $k$ ? Note that by a result of Hain, the Torelli groups are 1-formal for $g \geq 6$, which I understand to mean that there is some sort of Koszul duality between $\gr T$ and its **co**homology. Hence it doesn't sound absurd to me that there might be some relation between $\gr T$ itself and $H_*(T),$ but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing $\text{gr}\ T$ only tells you about cup products and higher Massey products on $H^1(T;\mathbb{Q})$.  Beyond that, there is no real relationship between $\text{gr}\ T$ and $H_{\ast}(T)$.

Your question is kind of vague, but I don't think there is anything known/conjectured beyond what is given in the Church-Farb paper you reference.